# Uninitialized constant Faker::Restaurant in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I've set up a rake task to populate my database, and although everything seems to be in place, it can't seem to find Faker.

Rake task:

```
require 'faker'

desc 'Populate db'
task :popdb => [:environment] do 
    puts 'Generating categories...'

    5.times do
        category = Category.create(title: Faker::Restaurant.name)
        puts "Created category \"" + category.title + "\""
        50.times do
            card = Card.create(
                retailer: Faker::Company.name,
                category: category,
                offer_type: Faker::Company.buzzword,
                first_purchase: Faker::Company.industry,
                credit_limit: Faker::Number.between(10, 50) * 10
                )
            puts "Created card \"" + card.title + "\""
        end
    end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'activeadmin'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I'm using the latest version of Faker, and I have the gem included in both test and development environments. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Please check the given answer below, feel free to accept/up vote answer for future SO if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually use the gem in rubygems.org which version is **1.9.1 - July 11, 2018** but **Faker::Restaurant** was add in 18 july and might be available in the next version in rubygems.org.

(see https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/restaurant.md)

Like suggested by the comment above use :

```
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', :branch => 'master'
```

This will download the gem from github instead of rubygems.org

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

If you are getting a `uninitialized constant Faker::[some_class]` error, your version of the gem is behind the one documented here. To make sure that your gem is the one documented here, change the line in your gemfile to:

```
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', :branch => 'master'
```

https://github.com/stympy/faker#installing